# Flights not available when trying to book

Tags: tickets, flight-search-engines

Why does Skyscanner show tickets available, but then when you go to the website, the company (Delta) says there are no more tickets?  But then when you do a subsequent search again, it says there are.

Comment: Their webpage updates the information every X time, e.g. 1 day. So sometimes the data is not updated. My personal recomendation: use google flights

Answer (score 8):

I have had this issue many times with Skyscanner. It’s a pain to use them  because one can’t trust their prices until one actually attempts to book the tickets. They simply seem to update their listing too slowly. I believe there’s nothing one can do aside from reporting the prices as not available when you go back to the skyscanner site.